# Transition Hook not working angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I want to listen for a transition success on my controller what i've done so far:

```
SignupController.$inject = ['$transitions'];

function SignupController($transitions) {
    var vm = this;

    vm.sample = $transitions.onSuccess({ to: 'sign-up', from: 'landing' }, function(){
        console.log("Something!");
    });
}

module.exports = SignupController;
```

The callback never executed whenever I navigate to 'sign-up' state for the first time. However, when i back and then navigate again to 'sign-up' it was executed.

Why is that so?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe check the $transitions.to() inside the success, but without specifing to/from:

```
$transitions.onSuccess({}, function($transitions) {
  var newState = $transitions.to();
  console.log('success moving to state', newState);
  // Do stuff depending on what state it moved to;
});
```